# Check if I can move GameObject with MeshCollider somewhere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm moving object using the simplest possible way, which is what I'm about to do before I learn better: On every `Update`, I move `transform.position` to `Vector3 destination` using `Vector3.MoveTowards`. Exactly speaking:

```
    private GameObject actor; //Object to move
    private void MakeMove()
    {
        //Move towards destination
        actor.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(actor.transform.position, destination, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        //Update HUD info
        actor.updatePosition();
        //Terminate running status if the target was reached
        if (actor.transform.position == destination && targetObj==null)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }
```

Two things suck about this:

1. The movement happens regardless to object rotation, isntead of moving forward
2. The object will pass through any other object to reach the target

Second problem is what I want to as here. Say I'd remember the original position before moving:

```
Vector3 oldPos = actor.transform.position;
actor.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards( ... );
//Get true if there an object colliding with the one that was just moved
if(actor.gameObject.collider.something something) {
     //revert back to old position
     actor.transform.position = oldPos;
}
```

The above is far from ideal. Still I don't even know how to implement such a simple solution. Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

**1**.Never try to move **meshcollider** and check against other colliders because a great amount of work needs to get done and it will make your FPS slow drastically. Use **compound collider** for complex models instead. furthermore add each collider to each one of your parts of model for an example use a capsule collider for arm and attach it to your arm object
**2**.For checking against collider use **OnCollisionEnter** , to check if you hit an object following segment can be used

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
              //get back to your last position
        }
```

**3**.Instead of moving around to find a way-through , use a **Path Finding algorithm** like **A*** or if you want a complete solution for your AI you can use ***RAIN***
**4**.If your gameobjects doesnt collide with each other should consider these important points

- 2 Triggers with no rigidbodies, nothing will happen.
- Same goes for 2 Colliders with no rigidbodies involved.
- 2 Colliders where one has a rigidbody attached will cause a
  Collision.
- Collider + Rigidbody and a Trigger will cause a Trigger.
- Trigger + Rigidbody and a Collider will also cause a Trigger.
- Trigger + Rigidbody and the second Trigger will again cause a Trigger.
- It does not matter if the rigidbody uses gravity or is kinematic but
  in all these cases the effect will only be there if the object with
  the rigidbody is moving